# How to understand this exception error in context?

Tags: cache, performance

I have been trying to fine tune the performance of a heavy page:
see [Category query very slow on multilingual site](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17273/category-query-very-slow-on-multilingual-site)

It appears that my initial hope of getting the page under 2 seconds was not quite accurate. 
After cache tagging the page the performance was great.
However I had left out an `{% endcache %}` tag - ie not closed it. This makes the performance in the network inspector less than 1 sec to load. Very nice.

However I am using Nginx microcaching set to 1 sec. As soon as I cleared the Nginx cache i started seeing the error in my template tag that was missing the closing cache tag.

So why does it load lightning fast with an unclosed tag?

When experimenting with placement of cache tags, I also managed to generate the following error in dev mode:

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template 
("Node "body" does not exist for Node "Craft\Cache_Node".").
```

I was wondering what exactly this means / indicates and if there is some interaction effect I am getting between craft cache and my Nginx server cache?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave off the closing `{% endcache %}` tag, then you should always get the error that you received with [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) enabled.  If devMode is disabled, you'll get the default 500 error template.

I would disable the nginx microcaching while you're testing this to make sure that you're not getting erroneous caching results.